# The specified network password is not correct when mapping share in Windows 10 & 11

Tags: networking, permissions, password, samba

After recent Windows 10 update and Samba update on my Ubuntu 20.04 server my Samba share no longer works (the share is not public or guest). When I attempt to map a share in Windows 10 & 11, I get the Windows Security, Enter network credentials “The specified network password is not correct”.

This occurs on both computers I access the share from. I have verified Linux user passwords, Samba user passwords, share name, Samba group names, etc. I have uninstalled and reinstalled Samba. I have also tried numerous changes to Windows Network settings and Samba configuration modifications with no success. I did install WSD on the Ubuntu server and can see the server icon in Windows Explorer.

After reinstalling Samba, I decided to start from scratch and configure new share and related settings. I used the process provided as described at the following link. https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-configure-samba-server-share-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux

Following is the smb.conf file created using this article as a guide and with modifications to define the [backups] share.

```
 [global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP (confirmed that WORKGROUP is set on both computers)
   server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   logging = file
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   server role = standalone server
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user
   usershare allow guests = yes
[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = no
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = yes
   guest ok = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700
[print$]
   comment = Printer Drivers
   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
   browseable = yes
   read only = yes
   guest ok = no

[homes]
   comment = Home Directories
   browseable = yes
   read only = no
   create mask = 0700
   directory mask = 0700
   valid users = %S

[backups]
  comment = public anonymous access
  path = /shares/backups/
  browsable = yes
  create mask = 0660
  directory mask = 0771
  writable = yes
  guest ok = yes
```

Next I verified the folders/directories for both shares:

```
[Home/art] share files
drwxr-xr-x   8 root root       4096 Apr 27 09:10 home
drwxr-xr-x 5 art       art       4096 Apr 28 11:39 art
-rw-rw-r-- 1 art  art     0 Apr 28 11:39 test.txt

[Backups] share
drwxrwxrwx   3 root root       4096 Apr 28 11:30 shares
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Apr 28 11:38 backups
-rwxrwxrwx 1 art art 0 Apr 28 11:38 test.txt
```

After verifying all of this, I attempted to map a drive to both shares using my linux/samba username and password. In each attempt, I received “The specified network password is not correct.”

I also tried these logins including the client computer name with the username lightning/art & lightning\art. These to fail. Including the client computer name worked prior to the updates described above.

Having these attempts fail, I tried accessing the shares on my android phone using AndSMB and on my Ipad.

Using Android AndSMb  with version set to SMB v2/v3 allows me to see the backups share directory, but triggers an error

```
USER art PASS ******
STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE(3221225581): Authentication failed for art using b.b.h.d.c@e1b1691
```

This app shows an icon for the server and when I click on the icon, the share folder(s) are listed, but I cannot see the test.txt file I created from the command line using Putty.

If I modify the settings to use SMBv1 allows me to see the share directory, but triggers errors “at hcifs.e.1.a(Unknown Source:199)” “at jcifs.h.c.run(Unknown Source:5)” and at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919).
I had the same results when attempting to access my home share with SMBv1 and SMBv2,v3.

Using my Ipad, I can create links to both the backups share and my home share. It seems to take my credentials, but when I click on the share folder, the test files in the shares as described in the android info are not shown. I get an error message “Content Unavailable The folder contents could not be displayed because of an unknown error”.

After running all of these tests and seeing the error messages, I feel like this must be a password authentication issue with Samba. I have consulted numerous articles and videos and have not found a likely cause or solution.
Any suggestions or recommendations?